# OCaml- Error when evaluating function (This expression has type 'a * 'b but an expression was expected of type ('a * 'b) list#)

Tags: ocaml

I am currently working on a function, that computes the difference of the two lists in the following way.

1. The input lists are sorted by the value of the key of type 'a.
2. The result includes the pairs from the first list with the keys
   that are not included in the second list.

**Example:
diff [(1,2);(2,3);(4,5)];(5,6)] [(2,4);(4,6)] → [(1,2);(5,6)]**

Now I am facing Error, I can't solve.

My code:

```
let rec diff list1 list2= match list1,list2 with
|x,[] -> [x]
| [],_->[]
| h1::t1,h2::t2 ->
    let (k1,v1) = h1  in
    let (k2,v2)=h2 in
    if(k1=k2) then diff t1 t2
    else if (k1>k2) then h1::(diff list1 t2)
    else h2::(diff t1 list2)
```

ERROR message:

> else if (k1>k2) then h1::(diff list1 t2) Error: This expression has
>   type 'a * 'b
>          but an expression was expected of type ('a * 'b) list#

**Working code:**

```
let rec diff list1 list2= match list1,list2 with
|_,[] -> list1
| [],_->[]
| h1::t1,h2::t2 ->
    let (k1,v1) = h1  in
    let (k2,v2)=h2 in
    if(k1=k2) then diff t1 t2
    else if (k1>k2) then h1::(diff list1 t2)
    else h1::(diff t1 list2)
```

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `list2` is empty, you return a list of lists containing `list1` (a.k.a. `x`). This tells OCaml that the return type is a list of lists of what the input lists contain. So when you later try to return just plain lists of tuples, rather than lists of lists of tuples, OCaml thinks that's the mistake.

But in fact returning a list of tuples is what you want. The mistake is returning a list of lists in the `x, []` case. You can fix that by changing that case to `| x, [] -> x` or `| _, [] -> list1`.